# Ajax LOAD funcion PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Buenas noches tengo un problema a la hora de actualizar un div con AJAX (Soy bastante nuevo y estoy haciendo pruebas)

Mi codigo javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    //DAR ME GUSTA
    $('.btnMG').click(function()
    {
        var usuario = "<?php echo $id ?>";
        var publicacion = this.id.substring(5,7);
        var div = document.getElementById('div'+publicacion);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/megusta.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {usuario: usuario, publicacion: publicacion},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function()
            {
                $('#div'+publicacion).load("parts/publicacion.php", {id: publicacion, usuario: usuario});

            }
        });
    });
    //FIN DAR ME GUSTA
    $('#btnPublicar').click(function()
    {
        var usuario = "<?php echo $id ?>";
        var texto = document.getElementById('textAreaPubli').value;
    });
});
```

Basicamente lo que necesito es que al dar a un boton de "Me gusta" se me refresque el div mostrando que ya se dio megusta a la publicacion.
El problema esta que cuando sucede el .load() el div se me queda en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hace la funcion que llamo en el .load() es la misma que uso para cargar todas las publicaciones al cargar la página..

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: porque .load() y no .append()? que es lo que quieres mostrar en el div?

Comment: Puedes poner todo el código HTML, así será más fácil ayudar.